# Access one element of a dictionary within dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a dynamic dictionary as follows:

```py
my_dict = {
    "file_name" : ""
}
my_dict = {
    "file_name" : "file_1.csv",
    "file_path" : "parent/folder/%s" % my_dict["file_name"]
}
```

I want `my_dict["file_path"]` to be equal to `"parent/folder/file_1.csv"`

How can I realize this?
I'm looking for a solution that will update "file_path" whenever "file_name" is updated.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve exactly but my guess is that you would be better off using simple custom class with @property setter or getter instead of dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this within the same statement as the `dict` is not initialised yet. You may try something like this:

```
my_dict = {
    "file_name" : "file_1.csv",
}
my_dict["file_path"] = "parent/folder/%s" % my_dict["file_name"]
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your response,

I've actually tried it and it's not exactly what I'm looking for.
Let's say, I edit "file_name" key mid code,
How can I be sure that "file_path" will also be updated?

Sorry, if I'm not clear enough

Comment: Unfortunately you can't dynamically update dict values depending on any other variable. What you can do is to create a function that returns the `file_path` and use that function instead of using the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a simple class. I think it's possible if you make the attributes both properties, make the setter for `file_name` set `file_path` as well, and disable the setter for `file_path`.

But a better option is to keep the dirname and basename separate, and have a path property that joins them. Here's a simple example:

```
import os

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, dirname, basename):
        self.dirname = dirname
        self.basename = basename

    # This method is not crucial to the example, just nice to add
    def __repr__(self):
        r = '{}({!r}, {!r})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            self.dirname,
            self.basename,
            )
        return r

    @property
    def path(self):
        return os.path.join(self.dirname, self.basename)

c = MyClass('parent/folder', 'file_1.csv')

print(c.path)  # -> parent/folder/file_1.csv

c.basename = 'foo.txt'

print(c.path)  # -> parent/folder/foo.txt

c.path = 'foo/bar.csv'  # -> AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

If you wanted, you could add a setter for `path` that uses `os.path.split` and sets `dirname` and `basename`.